# retrieve values after iteration

Tags: java, hashmap

After iterating over a "hashmap list", I want to write the values into a string as 'value 1' and 'value 2'. I cannot figure how?Can someone help me!

```
for (Object listItem : (List)value) {
System.out.println(key + ":" + listItem);
```

I have 2 values in my data. The above code gives me

Con:Name

Con:ID

Now, I want 'Name' to be value 1 and 'ID' to be value 2 so that I can replace and write them in the following string

```
"xxxxxxxxxx"+key+"xxxx"+value 1+"xxxxxxxxx"+value 2+"xxxxxxxxxx";
```

Comment: Where is `key` being defined?

Comment: Are `Con:Name` and `Con:ID` given in the same loop, or does it take two iterations to display them?

Comment: they are given in the same loop

Comment: So is `key` equal to the value `Con` in the `println` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String value1="";
String value2="";
int counter=0;

for (Object listItem : (List)value) {
    System.out.println(key + ":" + listItem);

    if(counter==0) {//first pass assign value to value1
       value1=listItem; 
       counter++;//increment for next pass
    }else if(counter==1) {//second pass assign value to value2
        value2=listItem;
        counter++;//so we dont keep re-assigning listItem for further iterations
    }

}

System.out.println(value1);//should display 'Name'
System.out.println(value2);//should display 'ID'
```

Comment: Thank you for ur response. But I want the ListItem be seperated as value 1 & value 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) class (assuming `key` is defined outside of the loop)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("xxxxxx" + key + "xxxx");
for (Object listItem : (List)value) {
    System.out.println(key + ":" + listItem);
    sb.append(listItem+"xxxxxxxxx");
}
```